# Passing pointer to function

Tags: c, pointers

I have a datatype, and I am trying to pass this datatype to another function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
static const int a[]= { 4, 5, 6, 7};

void call_func2(const int *c) {
    const int *d;
    d = c;
}

void func1() {
    const int *b;
    b = a;
    call_func2(b); // it would be also good, if i can directly pass a[] to call_func2
}

int main(void) {
    func1();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is `data_type` defined? Where is `c`, `d`, `e`, `f` and `g` defined?

Comment: You do include e.g. `test.h` in `test.c`?

Comment: Is it C or C++? Why is the title **Pass by reference**? I don't see it in your code.

Comment: Yes, and data_type is defined in test.h.

Comment: Also you should note that in C there is no "pass by reference". You can *emulate* it by using pointers, but to pass a pointer "by reference" you have to pass a pointer to the pointer. So in your code you don't really have any "references", you're just passing around a pointer to `data_type`, which just happens to be pointing to the first element in an array.

Comment: @thinkcool You should provide a full sample that other people can compile. Otherwise, it will likely be very difficult to solve this for you. Currently, there are a number of things missing that would restrict us from compiling this ourselves.

Comment: And regarding the point made by @sharth, please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question to include that.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, sharth created MCVE

Comment: How and where is `data_type` declared?

Comment: The error messages you posted do not match the code you posted. The code declares parameters as pointers to `const`. The error messages contain no `const`. Something is fake: either the code or the error messages. Please, post real information.

Comment: It is not clear what you tried to illustrate with your ideone link, since code at the link compiles in ideone without any errors.

Comment: I think, Joachim fixed it

Comment: This code has no problems

Comment: I think call_func(&b) should be passed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your MCVE, it's easy to see what the problem is (in the future, please include that code in the question instead of linking to it): You're passing a pointer to *constant* data to a function which takes a non-constant pointer.

You *can* pass a pointer to constant data to a function taking a non-constant pointer, if you *cast* the pointer. But beware that it might lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: I am trying to understand what fix you made in ideone.